# Laravel paginate (with foreign key)

Tags: laravel, laravel-pagination

I am trying to fetch some data out of a database with Laravel. The fetching part works fine, untill I want to use paginate for the data.

In my controller (RepairController) I use this function to get everyting (without pagination):

```
$pendingRepairs = Repair::get()->where('status.completed', 0);
```

This works fine. Untill I add the pagination function. Then it gives me an error:

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.
```

Some research on the internet shows me that I need to remove the ::get() part. But how? What is the alternative to use the get part, since I use the status.completed foreign key value?

My RepairController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repair;

class RepairController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $allRepairs = Repair::get();
        $pendingRepairs = Repair::get()->where('status.completed', 0)->paginate(2);
        $doneRepairs = $allRepairs->where('status.completed', 1);

        return view('repair.index', [
            'pendingRepairs' => $pendingRepairs, 'doneRepairs' => $doneRepairs
        ]);
    }
....
}
```

In Repair.php I have a link to the Statuses:

```
public function status() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Status::class);
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the replies.

I think they all will work. But I've found out the use of datatables (datatables.net).
Since that will add the pagination itself, I don't need the Larvel once anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `whereHas()` to add constraints on relationship.

```
$pendingRepairs = Repair::whereHas('status', function($query) {
    $query->where('completed', 0);
})
->paginate();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways to do that. First thing is whereHas as [Anurat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4264017/anurat-chapanond) answered.

There is also another way to just join table you need

In different situations they will work in different complexity.
Note, that whereHas will do `subselect`

```
$pendingRepairs = Repair::query()
    ->join('statuses', 'statuses.repair_id', 'repairs.id')
    ->where('statuses.completed', 0)
    ->select('repairs.*')
    ->paginate();
```

In case when your table names are: `repairs` `statuses` and you have `repair_id` foreign key, if not just replace them :)